# Can I use threads to parse information and coordinate db insertion?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a software in java that performs the following functions.
1) Listen a MQ queue
2) When a message arrive, it needs to parse the information to json
3) Based on message information, it needs to perform data enrichment, querying a database
4) Insert/Update new data into database

My doubt is about the last part. I think I do steps 1, 2 and 3 using threads to speed up my application, because it can be executed concurrently without problems.
The last part (step 4) needs to be coordinated in a way that it insert/update information into database in the same order that messages arrived at MQ queue (older to newer) sequentially.

Today, my application works without threads, so it process all steps sequentially (one message per execution) without concurrency problems, but I know that steps 1, 2, 3 can be executed concurrently without problems. Is there a way to do what I need?

I really appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: You don't need to use threads.  You should have a message driven bean that does the work.  Your database connections should be pooled.  You will need a transaction manager with appropriate isolation set.  You should get it working properly and measure performance before you start worrying about whether it's fast enough.

Comment: I Agree with @duufymo, you need a transaction manager like spring-tx.

Comment: step 3 implies querying a database, so also must be executed in the order of messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should think about the threads only if you foresee or actually facing any performance issue.That depend on expected load and performance. Going for thread is also a overhead/cost sometime because it needs coordination . Also doing multi thread on single core processor will make the things worse

So go for it if you see performance issue based on expected load provided you have enough cores supporting